# SQL Server can't connect to InstallShield Installer when using TLS 1.2 only

Tags: sql-server, ssl, tls1.2, installshield

I'm getting this error message when trying to connect to the database during the installation process when disabling everything but TLS 1.2 in Windows registry

```
*Error 27502. Could not connect to Microsoft SQL Server '(local)'. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error. (18)*. I've tried it on SQL Server 2012 and 2016.
```

I'm using SQL Server Standard Edition or above and trying it in versions 2012, 2014, and 2016.

The main things I've tried so far:

Upgrading to InstallShield 2019 R3: https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/NewFeatureIS2019.htm

Installing SQL Server driver `MSOLEDBSQL`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: SQL Server uses self-signed X.509 certificates by default. Have you tried adding `TrustServerCertificate=false;` to your connection string?

Comment: Do you use SQL Sever or SQL Server Express?

Comment: @DoNhuVy It's Sql Server, not express

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks for the feedback. I wasn't aware of that setting for the connection string and it isn't in the connection so far. However false is the default value and so it shouldn't make a difference if I put the property in there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-encryption-without-validation?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=In%20addition%2C%20a%20new%20connection,values%3B%20false%20is%20the%20default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I installed the driver MSOLEDBSQL, I didn't change the provider in the connection string to MSOLEDBSQL in InstallShield. Doing this and making the MSOLEDBSQL driver an InstallShield prerequisite made it work correctly.

Comment: I am having the same problem, would you mind sharing where in InstallShield you actually went to update the Connection String Provider?

Comment: Ok, I think I found where. On the left panel, go to Server Configuration -> SQL Scripts. Then on the right side click on your SQL Connection (the entry below "SQL Scripts") and then click on the tab "Requirements". On the bottom we have a "Choose a Driver for Database Sever"